# Do any Targets share their dependencies with their dependencies around them?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings, xcode-target

I have an Xcode project which built by using Tuist.
The main app target has following dependencies(Link binary with Libraries):
HomeModule, HomeModuleInterface, LoginModule, LoginModuleInterface, NetworkKit and so on.
[image]

When I built-compile-run the app target,There are no issues that Xcode throws.
[image]

But here is the issue and the point that I want to ask:
LoginModule, can import HomeModule target and HomeModuleInterfaces but the problem is, LoginModule has no Dependencies to HomeModule, you can see it below.

[image]

Until now project can run, xcode can build without no issue. When it comes to compiling only LoginModule, Xcode throws an error, "There is no such a module HomeModule" and if I add HomeModule dependencies to LoginModule, I can compile the LoginModule target without error again.

[image]

**What causes that, the main app target have all dependencies, are these dependencies shared between modules-targets or other dependencies that linked to related target ? How it can be possible ?**